# Application cannot be started error in ClickOnce deployment

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, deployment, clickonce, rights

I have an application created in Visual C# using ClickOnce.
I send this application to users via a zipped ClickOnce publish folder, however I (the developer) cannot install it, while others have no problems.

I do the following steps:
- In VS 2010, Project settings, Publish tab, click button 'Publish Now'
- In the created directory I run setup (this is the created ClickOnce Setup file)
- I get the error dialog: Application cannot be started. Contact the application vendor.

Btw, I have not signed my application and assigned the application as a Full Trust application.

What I already tried (also according comments):
- When run as administrator (RMB on setup in clickonce in local folder), I get the same error.
- When running it directly from the bin directory, it works ok.
- When adding a sleep for attaching a debugger, it immediately gives the same error.
- I cleared the cache but it does not help.

And below are the complete details:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.261
System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.245 (RTMGDR.030319-2400)
clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.261 (RTMGDR.030319-2600)
dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.1 (RTMRel.030319-0100)
dfshim.dll          : 4.0.31106.0 (Main.031106-0000)

SOURCES
Deployment url          : file:///D:/PcgTools%20Publish2/PcgTools.application
Application url         : file:///D:/PcgTools%20Publish2/Application%20Files/PcgTools_0_5_0_149/PcgTools.exe.manifest

IDENTITIES
Deployment Identity     : PcgTools.application, Version=0.5.0.149, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0000000000000000, processorArchitecture=msil

APPLICATION SUMMARY
* Installable application.

ERROR SUMMARY
Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
* Activation of D:\PcgTools Publish2\PcgTools.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
    + Specified cast is not valid.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
* The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.
* The manifest for this application does not have a signature. Signature validation will be ignored.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
* [12-3-2012 2:18:04] : Activation of D:\PcgTools Publish2\PcgTools.application has started.
* [12-3-2012 2:18:04] : Processing of deployment manifest has successfully completed.
* [12-3-2012 2:18:04] : Installation of the application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
Following errors were detected during this operation.
* [12-3-2012 2:18:04] System.InvalidCastException
    - Specified cast is not valid.
    - Source: System.Deployment
    - Stack trace:
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.VerifyRequestedPrivilegesSupport(String requestedExecutionLevel)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
        at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadApplicationManifest(AssemblyManifest deploymentManifest, String targetDir, Uri deploymentUri, Uri& appSourceUri, String& appManifestPath)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.DownloadApplication(SubscriptionState subState, ActivationDescription actDesc, Int64 transactionId, TempDirectory& downloadTemp)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.InstallApplication(SubscriptionState& subState, ActivationDescription actDesc)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
        at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
No transaction information is available.
```

Comment: Does your application launch when not run from click once?

Comment: @M.Babcock The only way I can launch it is via MS Visual Studio itself, either by run or debug (normally I use debug mode only). It also runs from the bin directory.

Comment: You can't run it by double clicking the EXE produced?

Comment: @M.Babcock Yes it also runs from the bin directory (had to check it to be sure).

Comment: Can you publish it to a local file share and run it from there? Alternatively, you may consider putting some kind of wait in the startup of the application (long enough to attach the debugger manually) and see if you can walk through it that way.

Comment: @M.Babcock That is what I'm doing now (if I understand the term 'local file share' well). It's now created on D:\Publish2 and I cannot run it from there but when I zip it, email it then others can install it via that file.

Comment: See the update to my comment.

Comment: Ok I will try that (can take some time though because I have to leave now) ... thanks for the great tip.

Comment: Somewhere in the startup of your application you are getting a "Specified cast is not valid."  are you calling clickonce in code ?

Comment: Try clearing your existing clickonce cache.  From the command line, try running either `mage -cc` or `rundll32 dfshim CleanOnlineAppCache`

Comment: @M.Babcock I tried it but it still gives the error (immediately), probably it is in the installation process.

Comment: @Micah Armantrout No I don't use clickonce in the code itself.

Comment: @scott.korin I tried to clean the online cache (last command; first one was not recognized), but did not help.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers - Did you try launching the install as Administrator?

Comment: @M.Babcock Yes as administrator I get the same error.

Comment: @MichelKeijzers - To clarify, you right clicked on the setup produced and selected _Run as Administrator_ correct?

Comment: @M.Babcock Yes exactly as you wrote.